# Run time error '13' type mismatch, if replace long with int then run time error '6' overflow

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and am trying to design a program that will go through a column with Strings in it and for every unique String name create a new worksheet object with that String value as its name and then copy and paste the values in that row to the new sheet. All identical Strings should then also have the values in their row copied over to the new sheet.

I'm getting a run time error '13' type mismatch at the part of my code where I try to calculate a cell value while inputting longs. For example: Cells(long x, long y).Value. I've tried changing the values to ints to avoid the issue but then I get an run time error '6' overflow error even though my document is only 2272 rows long and the error is occurring before the code has even gone through one iteration of the loop.
Here's the code:

```
Sub FilterByClass()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim sheetName As String

ActiveSheet.Name = "AllClasses"
sheetName = Worksheets("AllClasses").Cells(2, 1).Value
Worksheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = sheetName
Worksheets("AllClasses").Activate
ActiveSheet.Rows("1:2").Copy
Worksheets(sheetName).Paste
j = 3
k = 0
For i = 3 To Rows.Count
     If Worksheets("AllClasses").Cells(i, 1).Value <> Worksheets("AllClasses").Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
        Worksheets("AllClasses").Rows("1:1, j:(i-1)").Copy ***Where the error takes place
        Worksheets(Worksheets("AllClasses").Cells((i - 1), 1).Value).Paste
        j = i
        sheetName = Worksheets("AllClasses").Cells(i, 1).Value
        For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook
        If sheetName = sheet.Name Then k = 1
        Next sheet
    If k = 1 Then k = 0
    Else
        Worksheets.Add
        ActiveSheet.Name = sheetName
        Worksheets("AllClasses").Activate
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated. And if you see anything in the rest of the code that looks like it clearly won't work as intended please point it out as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a string literal when you should not be.

`Worksheets("AllClasses").Rows("1:1, j:(i-1)").Copy`

The *literal* assignment is "1:1, j:(i-1)" and this part is the problem: j:(i-1).

Anything *inside* of the quotation marks is a literal string. it is not being evaluated to the integer/long value that you are storing in the variables `j` and `i`.

The `Type Mismatch` is because you're sending a string where a long/integer is expected.

Keep your variables declared `As Long`, and change that line this, to use Range instead of Rows object:

```
Worksheets("AllClasses").Range("1:1," & i-1 & ":" & j).Copy
```

Comment: Also if what you said is the case why would I be getting an overflow error instead of the same type mismatch error when I replace my longs with ints?

Comment: Same line? What is the value of `i` and `j` when the error happens?

Comment: Same line, and it's the first iteration of the loop so they're both still equal to 3

Comment: OK, what do you want that line to do?

Comment: It looks like you want to copy row 1 **and** some other row(s)? Is that correct?

Comment: If the String in this row is not equal to the string in the last row than copy the first row of the worksheet and - in this first case - rows 3 through the row where the string name no longer matches(non-inclusive), then in the next line paste it to a different worksheet

Comment: Worked great, but I found a later flaw in my code that I just spent all this time correcting. However, now I'm getting an "application defined or object defined" error at my If statement even though the code I changed shouldn't be affecting that. Please help!